# Position of element with display: inline-block and position: relative not updating with resize in IE11

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position a div along a line with a position that is calculated at runtime. I've set the div's display to inline-block (in the full code there are elements inside the div) and the position to relative, but the position doesn't update properly in IE11 when resizing the window.

https://jsfiddle.net/cpmckinn/ys4zjLam/2/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="marker">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="line">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  width: 50%;
}

.marker {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width: auto;

}
```

```
$(".marker").css("left","50%")
```

Everything checks out in Chrome and Firefox, and I can force the div's position to update in IE11 by disabling and re-enabling the "left" style with the developer tools. Is there a workaround to this particular issue or a better way to handle positioning the div?